# Setup custom SSL from Google Apps, redirection loops

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, google-apps

I follow this tutorial: https://support.google.com/a/answer/2644334

At the step 4, when I enter the Application ID of my App Engine app, and I click on Enable SSL for App Engine Applications, and I get an error "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" for "https://appengine.google.com/start".

I have tried with Chrome, Safari, and Chromium. With a cleared cache.

Do you have any suggestion which could help me?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  I have the same problem.

Comment: No... So for the moment I do without...

Comment: The email address you are using - has it been signed up for a google apps account before, deleted, and now recreated with the same email? This appears to cause the issue from what I can find googling similar threads. If this isn't the case, please reply with as much relevant info about your particular configuration of accounts, domains, etc. as possible.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Also, it was on an early, "free" Google Apps for Business accout.  We initially connected a 2ndary domain name, but there was a rule that you can't use SSL for the non-primary domain, and you can't change the primary domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a different superuser account in Google Apps worked to enable SSL.  No clue why.

Once it was enabled by the other account, my original superuser account could be used to upload and manage the SSL Certs.

Comment: Is there any permission differences between the two superuser accounts? And as far as my earlier question - was the first superuser account previously signed up for a google apps account, deleted then recreated?

Comment: The 2nd admin user was also originally named in the first Apps account...  The only difference I can think of between the 1st and 2nd users in the new Apps account is tautological -- the 2nd user was added to the 2nd account, rather than the 1st user who created the 2nd Apps account.